# Make directory structure from forward slashes

Tags: linux, windows, bash, shell, unix

Im pulling an html document from a windows machine onto my linux box and the issue is the directory structure is not maintained between the two. This is how it looks in linux

```
MyReport\partition_and_timing.files\img0.jpg
MyReport\partition_and_timing.html
MyReport\protocols_cards.html
MyReport\report_title.files\img0.jpg
MyReport\report_title.html
MyReport\scripts.html
```

Im thinking of using a bash script that will change the "\" into a "/" essentially making a folder. Im guessing their is a standard way of doing this but cannot figure it out.

This is what Im working with

```
for file in *; do mv $file echo $file | sed 's/\\/\//g' ; done
```

Comment: Using [tag:cygwin], you can actually just use forward slashes.  The system knows to convert them for you.

Comment: Since this is an HTML document they should be forward slashes, even in Windows.  The browser will convert them to backward slashes for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `mv $file ${file//\\/\/}`. it substitutes each backslash with a forward slash in `${file}`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to capture

```
 echo $file | sed 's/\\/\//g'
```

Because now you're moving a file, a non-existing file named 'echo' into file, and pipe the (erroneous) result to a sed that can't handle it.

Answer (score 0):

let `file` have the list of files you want to modify:

```
for f in $file; do
    cp "$f" "$f".backup
    sed -i 's/\\/\//g' $f
done
```

it's a for loop in which a backup file is created first, then use `sed` to do inplace modification.

`-i` of sed means you want to do inplace modification, so the modification will be applied to file directly.